# EntranceThemeTransition not working on UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

Do the transitions work in apps for the Universal Windows Plattform (UWP) / Windows 10?

I pasted the following code into an empty page, but the animation wouldn't work.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="rectangleItems">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Height="400"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- The sequence children appear depends on their order in 
     the panel's children, not necessarily on where they render
     on the screen. Be sure to arrange your child elements in
     the order you want them to transition into view. -->
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntranceThemeTransition works on UWP. You can set `IsStaggeringEnabled` to **true** and get the animation even if the items are already there (your case).

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, I have a new project and copied the code above then added IsStaggeringEnabled="True". But I still get no animation. I think I'm missing something here. Is there something that I need to do before I can use some transitions?